# Google UI Apps Script: Blank PDF when converting spreadsheet to PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I have a piece of code I am testing, in an attempt to learn how to convert a spreadsheet into a pdf using Google UI Apps Script. The code creates and writes to the spreadsheet but the pdf attachment is blank. Would appreciate any help to get this to work. Thanks.

```
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("My Test Sheet");
var columnNames = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Department"];
newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();

var headersRange = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, 1, columnNames.length);
headersRange.setValues([columnNames]);

var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var attach = {fileName:'My Test PDF.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

// Send email 
MailApp.sendEmail("myemail@email.com", "subject", "message", {attachments:[attach]});
```

Comment: note that you could use MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "subject", "message", {attachments:[attach]});
 without having to hardcode your email...

Answer (score 0):

You should not use DocList anymore. Use DriveApp instead. Below a solution with little modifications of your code:

```
function toPdf(id){
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
// var ssDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
  var ssDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
 var pdf = DriveApp.createFile(ssDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
  return pdf.getBlob().getBytes();
}


function user2943227(){
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("My Test Sheet");
  var columnNames = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Department"];
//  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();

  var headersRange = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, 1, columnNames.length);
  headersRange.setValues([columnNames]);

//  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var pdf = toPdf(newSpreadsheet.getId());
  var attach = {fileName:'My Test PDF.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send email 
  MailApp.sendEmail("myemail@email.com", "subject", "message", {attachments:[attach]});

}
```

Comment: DocsList works fine too, the only change that was useful was adding the 'flush' so that spreadsheet gets updated before conversion.

Comment: @Sergeinsas me dit pas que tu ne penses pas que doclist est voué à mourrir! Il est plus vieux que drive et il est toujours en mode "experimental". Ca sent la vielle chaussette doclist. Ceci dit il est vrai que je n'ai pas verifié le code d'origine, mais le code que j'ai posté marche.